# How to iterate list of elements in spring web flux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

```
We have the following list of elements in JSON form, how can we iterate the below list using spring webflux. While iteration we have to return the response as well. 

   "units": [
                {
                    "unitTitle": "unit1",
                    "unitNumber": 1,
                    "chapters": [
                        {
                            "chapterTitle": "ch1",
                            "chapterNumber": 1,
                            "modules": [
                                {
                                    "moduleName": "module",
                                    "moduleNumber": 1,
                                    "sections": [
                                        {
                                            "sectionName": "section1",
                                            "sectionNumber": 1
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "chapterTitle": "Ch2",
                            "chapterNumber": 2,
                            "modules": [
                                {
                                    "moduleName": "module2",
                                    "moduleNumber": 1,
                                    "sections": [
                                        {
                                            "sectionName": "section2",
                                            "sectionNumber": 1
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]

I have tried with concatMap :

    Flux.fromStream(generateTocRequest.getVolumes().stream()).concatMap(volume -> {
                String title = !StringUtils.isBlank(volume.getVolumeTitle()) ? volume.getVolumeTitle() : "";
                return createTOCContainer(new Container(projectUrn, TocConstants.VOLUME.toLowerCase(), parentEntityUrn, TocConstants.BODYMATTER, 0), title, token, isAutoNumberingEnabled)
                        .flatMap(containerVolume -> {
                    if ( !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(volume.getUnits()) && containerVolume != null ) {
                        volumeList.add(containerVolume.getEntityUrn());

                        Flux.fromStream(volume.getUnits().stream()).concatMap(unit -> {
                            String unitTitle = !StringUtils.isBlank(unit.getUnitTitle()) ? unit.getUnitTitle() : "";
                            return createTOCContainer(new Container(projectUrn, TocConstants.PART.toLowerCase(), parentEntityUrn, TocConstants.BODYMATTER, 0), unitTitle, token, isAutoNumberingEnabled)
                                    .flatMap(containerUnit -> {
                                if ( !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(unit.getChapters()) && containerUnit != null ) {

                                    Flux.fromStream(unit.getChapters().stream()).concatMap(chapter -> {

                                        String chapterName = !StringUtils.isBlank(chapter.getChapterTitle()) ? chapter.getChapterTitle() : "";
                                    return createTOCContainer(new Container(projectUrn, TocConstants.CHAPTER.toLowerCase(), containerUnit.getEntityUrn(), TocConstants.BODYMATTER, 0), chapterName, token, isAutoNumberingEnabled)
                                                .flatMap(containerChapter -> {
                                            if ( !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(chapter.getModules()) && containerChapter != null ) {

                                                Flux.fromStream(chapter.getModules().stream()).concatMap(module -> {
                                                    String moduleName = !StringUtils.isBlank(module.getModuleName()) ? module.getModuleName() : "";
                                                    return createTOCContainer(new Container(projectUrn, TocConstants.MODULE.toLowerCase(), containerChapter.getEntityUrn(), TocConstants.BODYMATTER, 0), moduleName, token, isAutoNumberingEnabled)
                                                     .flatMap(containerModule -> {

                                                        if ( !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(module.getSections()) && containerModule != null ) {

                                                            Flux.fromStream(module.getSections().stream()).concatMap(section -> {

                                                                String sectionName = !StringUtils.isBlank(section.getSectionName()) ? section.getSectionName() : "";
                                                                createTOCContainer(new Container(projectUrn, TocConstants.SECTION.toLowerCase(), containerChapter.getEntityUrn(), TocConstants.BODYMATTER, 0), sectionName, token, isAutoNumberingEnabled);
                                                                return Mono.empty();
                                                            });
                                                        } else {
                                                            createTOCContainer(new Container(projectUrn, TocConstants.SECTION, containerModule.getEntityUrn(), TocConstants.BODYMATTER, 0), "", token, isAutoNumberingEnabled);
                                                        }
                                                        return Mono.just(containerModule);
                                                    });
                                                });
                                            }
                                            return Mono.just(containerChapter);
                                        });

                                    });
                                }

                                return Mono.just(containerUnit);
                            });


                        });

                    }
                    return Mono.just(containerVolume);
                });
            });

//createTocContainer method call which is being called in previous function
```

//createTocContainer method call which is being called in previous function
//createTocContainer method call which is being called in previous function
//createTocContainer method call which is being called in previous function
//createTocContainer method call which is being called in previous function

```
public Mono<ContainerMetadata> createTOCContainer(final Container containerRequest, final String title, final String token, boolean isAutoNumberingEnabled) {
        String metaData = null;
        LOGGER.info("Inside StructureServiceImpl.createTOCContainer");
        final ContainerMetadata[] containerMetaData = new ContainerMetadata[1];
        String uri = tocStructureApiBaseUrl + tocStructureContextPath + TocConstants.SEPERATOR + containerRequest.getProjectUrn()
                + TocConstants.SEPERATOR + TocConstants.CONTAINER + TocConstants.SEPERATOR
                + containerRequest.getParentEntityUrn() + TocConstants.SEPERATOR
                + TocConstants.SECTION + TocConstants.SEPERATOR + TocConstants.BODYMATTER
                + TocConstants.SEPERATOR + TocConstants.CHILD_CONTAINER;

        HttpHeaders headers = Header.buildAuthorizationHeader(token);
        try {
            return createContainerMetaData(containerRequest, token, uri)
                    .flatMap(result->{
                        containerMetaData[0] = gson.fromJson(result, ContainerMetadata.class);
                        LOGGER.info("container meta data obtained via tocStructureApi call : [{}]", containerMetaData[0]);

                        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(title))
                            renameTocContainer(title,  containerRequest.getProjectUrn(),  containerMetaData[0].getEntityUrn(), token);
                        LOGGER.info("Title has been updated");
                        if(isAutoNumberingEnabled)
                            LOGGER.info("StructureAPIService.addContainerMetaData()");
                        addContainerMetaData(metaData.toString(), containerRequest, token, Boolean.TRUE).subscribe();


                        return Mono.just(containerMetaData[0]);
                    });

        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Container element creation failed for the Container and Title [{} {}]", containerRequest.getParentEntityUrn(), title);
            return Mono.just(containerMetaData[0]);
        }
    }
But that is not iterating the elements, any suggestion for the same to achieve the result in iterative form.
```

Comment: It's very hard to read the provided examples. Can you please fix it so others will be able to help you.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov There is a list of elements in JSON format, passing as request body in API call  using Spring Web Flux we want to Iterate the these list of elements.

Comment: I mean the code you pasted is unreadable because of broken formatting. I suggest to edit the question and fix the formatting, so people could actually look at it

Comment: @IgorArtamonov oh it was broken formatting, now updated it